# Date picker in c#/selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a date cell in a calendar control on my site with the following code

```
<td class=calendar-day" is="null"><a id="8-29" class="calendar-day-link" data-date="2016-08-29" aria-selected="false" title="August 29,2016" is="null">
```

I need a method where i specify a string eg "8-21" and it then cycles through all the values in the calendar and select the one that matches "8-21" and clicks

This is the method i tried which failed

```
IWebElement option = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("calendar-day-‌​link"), 5);
List<IWebElement> Links = new List<IWebElement>(DriverContext.Driver.FindElements(By.Class‌​Name("calendar-day-l‌​ink"), 5));
    for (int k = 0; k < Links.Count; k++)
    {
        if (Links[k].Text == date)
        {
            option = Links[k];
        }
    }
option.Click();
```

Comment: Please improve html code (with formatting) and show us what you have already done.

Comment: please edit your question, comments are unreadable

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: what type of error do you get?

Comment: i dont get an error it just doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html code the anchor tag contains date as its id.You can directly use the required date and use cssSelector to click on date from the calendar. try the below code

```
IWebElement option = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a#"+date), 5);
option.Click();
```